# Time to send bitcoins?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, confirmations, sending, investing

I was investing bitcoins in Coin Controller but I need the time to send it because they only give you 10 minutes. So I want to know how to calculate the time to send bitcoin with for an example 0.00005 transaction fee. I know that you can't calculate it but do you know how long it would take if I send 0.00015 and the transaction fee is 0.00005 (the half of a normal transaction fee).

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that an investment - I'd call it more of a pyramid scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time required for your transaction to be broadcasted over the network is normally a few milliseconds. A high HD utilization, an outdated processor or many small unspent outputs in your wallet can delay the time required by your client to perform the broadcasting.

The time, however, required for your transaction to get **one** confirmation, assuming that your client is synched and the transaction itself is valid and carries the right fee to get included right away into the next block, is currently around 8 minutes ([6:45 to 8:43 minutes over the past 30 days](https://blockchain.info/charts/avg-confirmation-time?timespan=30days&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=0&address=)).